# Accessing geojson feature from pointtomarker in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet

I'm trying to my geojson feature 'type_id' to add my json data to different layers.

```
OnEachPlant = (latlngTemp) ->
  switch ''.feature.properties.type_id
    when '2'
      myIcon = L.divIcon(
        className: 'sIcon'
        html: 'S' )
      shrubMarkers.addLayer L.marker(latlngTemp, {icon: myIcon})
    when '3'
      myIcon = L.divIcon(
        className: 'tIcon'
        html: 'T' )
      treeMarkers.addLayer L.marker(latlngTemp, {icon: myIcon})
```

$.ajax
    dataType: 'text'
    url: 'map.json'
    success: (data) ->
      L.geoJSON(JSON.parse(data),
        pointToLayer: (feature, latlng) ->
          OnEachPlant(latlng))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you are running `OnEachPlant()` as the `pointToLayer()` method.

Let me quote from the [Leaflet docs](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.2.html#geojson):

> `pointToLayer`: A Function defining how GeoJSON points spawn Leaflet layers. It is internally called when data is added, passing the GeoJSON point feature and its `LatLng`. The default is to spawn a default `Marker`:
>
> ```
> function(geoJsonPoint, latlng) {
>     return L.marker(latlng);
> }
> ```

So, if you define a `pointToLayer` function, such a function **must** receive two arguments, and **must** return an instance of `L.Layer` (a `L.Marker`, a `L.Circle`, or whatever). Furthermore, this is explained in the [Leaflet GeoJSON tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/).

I guess what you want to do is along the lines of:

```
function plantToMarker(feat, latlng) {
  var icon:
  switch (feat.properties.type_id) {
    case 2:
    case '2':
      icon = L.divIcon({html: 'S'});
      break;
    case 3:
    case '3':
      icon = L.divIcon({html: 'T'});
      break;
    // rest of case statements for the switch go here
  }
  return L.marker(latlng, icon);
}

$.ajax({
  url: whatever,
  success: (data)-> {
    L.geoJSON(data, {
      pointToLayer: plantToMarker
    })
  }
})
```

Note the use or `return L.marker()` in the function, and how the function definition is passed directly as an option for the `L.GeoJSON` factory.